# How to delete files older than x days from SFTP server in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sftp, winscp, winscp-net

The below PowerShell script connects to my SFTP sever and deletes all my files under the path `/test/my_file/.`

Is there a way where I can say only delete files that is five days old under the path `/test/my_file/`.

```
Add-Type -Path " WinSCPnet.dll"

$sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
    Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Sftp
    HostName = "example.test.com"
    UserName = "username"
    Password = "password"
    SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-rsa 1234 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx"
}

$sessionOptions.AddRawSettings("ProxyMethod", "0")
$sessionOptions.AddRawSettings("ProxyHost", "123.45.67.8")
$sessionOptions.AddRawSettings("ProxyPort", "8080")

$session = New-Object WinSCP.Session

try
{
    $session.Open($sessionOptions)

    # Remove files
    $session.RemoveFiles("/test/my_file/*").Check()
}
finally
{
    $session.Dispose()
}
```

The files have names like:

```
Test_File_20180315.csv
Test_File_20180316.csv
Test_File_20180319.csv
Test_File_20180320.csv
Test_File_20180321.csv
Test_File_20180322.csv
Test_File_20180323.csv
Test_File_20180326.csv
Test_File_20180327.csv
Test_File_20180328.csv
Test_File_20180329.csv
Test_File_20180330.csv
Test_File_20180402.csv
Test_File_20180403.csv
Test_File_20180404.csv
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

If you can use **modification time** of the files, it's easy. Just use a [time constraint in the file mask](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask#size_time):

```
$session.RemoveFiles("/test/my_file/*<5D").Check()
```

---

But if you need to select the files by the **timestamp in their name**, it's more difficult. Luckily your file names seem to have a nice fixed format `Test_File_yyyymmdd.csv`, so you can select those that *sort* before `Test_File_yyyymmdd.csv` where `yyyymmdd` is 5 days old:

```
$limit = [System.DateTime]::Today.AddDays(-5).ToString("yyyyMMdd")

$session.ListDirectory("/test/my_file").Files |
    Where-Object { !$_.IsDirectory } |
    Where-Object { $_.Name -lt ("Test_File_" + $limit) } |
    ForEach-Object { 
        Write-Host ("Deleting {0} ..." -f $_.Name)
        $session.RemoveFiles($_.FullName).Check()
    }
```

*(of course, first do a dry test with the `RemoveFiles` call removed)*

See also WinSCP article on [formatting relative timestamps in PowerShell](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_formatting_timestamp_batch_file#powershell).

Answer (score 0):

In one script I use, I have multiple operations to perform, but at the end I delete files older than a few days. So, I fetch all the files once at the beginning and then at the end remove them.

Minimal code would look like:

```
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Path\To\WinSCP\WinSCPnet.dll'

# Midnight 5 days ago
$DeletionDate = [System.DateTime]::Today.AddDays(-5)

$SessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{ ... }

$Session = New-Object WinSCP.Session
$Session.Open($SessionOptions)

$RemoteFiles = $Session.ListDirectory($RemotePath).Files | Where-Object { !$_.IsDirectory }

# My other processes are here

$RemoteFiles | 
    Where-Object LastWriteTime -lt $DeletionDate |
    ForEach-Object {
        $RemoveFilesResult = $Session.RemoveFiles($_.FullName)
        $RemoveFilesResult.Check()
    }
```

Comment: How do i use your code and link it with mine because i need to connect to a sftp and delete files form there?